# How to store product data in magento store?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, curl

I'm getting product data through an api call and now i want to store this data in my magento store? can anyone help me out to store without duplication

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://magento.com/component/controller.php",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "appid: 9",
    "appkey: 0325615546",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "data: {   \"1474614118_1\": [ \"147461411870027\",\"147461411870027\"]    }",
"functionname: get_products_by_ids",
"postman-token: fd83165f-51e2-4e26-c15f-df5aba3250d7"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Respose:

```
"data": {
    "get_products_by_ids": [
      {
        "product_id": 0,
        "name": "Fresco 2 pc",
        "description": "Light Weight  Cotton Blend Fabric 2 Pc. White color kameez with round neck, full sleeves, embroidery on the front paired with shalwar.",
        "meta_title": "Fresco 2 pc",
        "meta_description": "",
        "meta_keyword": "",
        "tag": "1474614118",
        "model": "E02516-WHT",
        "sku": "1474614118E02516-WHT",
        "upc": "1474614118",
        "ean": "1474614118",
        "jan": "1474614118",
        "isbn": "",
        "mpn": "1474614118",
        "location": "",
        "quantity": "0",
        "stock_status": "Out Of Stock",
        "image": "http://www.wearego.com/image/catalog/eid2/E02516-WHT.JPG",
        "manufacturer_id": null,
        "manufacturer": null,
        "price": "3950.0000",
        "special": "1580.0000",
        "reward": null,
        "points": "0",
        "tax_class_id": "14746141180",
        "date_available": "2016-09-08",
        "weight": "0.50000000",
        "weight_class_id": "14746141181",
        "length": "0.00000000",
        "width": "0.00000000",
        "height": "0.00000000",
        "length_class_id": "14746141181",
        "subtract": "1",
        "rating": 0,
        "reviews": 0,
        "minimum": "1",
        "sort_order": "1",
        "status": "1",
        "date_added": "2016-09-08 23:03:57",
        "date_modified": "2016-09-08 23:03:57",
        "viewed": "3899",
        "vendor_id": "1474614118",
        "addtionalimages": [
            {
                "product_image_id": "14746141184247",
                "product_id": "147461411870027",
                "image": "http://www.wearego.com/image/catalog/eid2/E02516-WHT-01.JPG"
            },
            {
                "product_image_id": "14746141184248",
                "product_id": "147461411870027",
                "image": "http://www.wearego.com/image/catalog/eid2/E02516-WHT-02.JPG"
            }
        ],
        "options": [],
        "categories": []
      }
]
```

}

Comment: Depends on the output of `$response`, but basically you can just create (or load) a product and save the data using the `set` methods. Could you update the question and add the content of `$response`?

Comment: @ArjenMiedema i have now added content of response

Answer (score 1):

Saving this data into a product is pretty easy, although setting the values needs your own interpretation. Magento uses the `setData` method to set the product data.

So it should look like something like this:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://magento.com/component/controller.php",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "appid: 9",
    "appkey: 0325615546",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "data: {
        "1474614118_1": [ 
            "147461411870027",
            "147461411870027"
        ]
    }",
    "functionname: get_products_by_ids",
    "postman-token: fd83165f-51e2-4e26-c15f-df5aba3250d7"
  )
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  $data = json_decode($response);

  foreach ($data->get_products_by_ids as $item) {
      $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

      if ($item->product_id) {
          $product->load($item->product_id);
      }

      $product->setSku($item->sku)
          ->setEan($item->ean)
          // Continue setting all other attribute values
          ->save();

      $stockItem = $product->getStockItem();
      $stockItem->setQty($item->quantity)
          ->setIsInStock($item->quantity > 0)
          ->save();
  }
}
```

It might be clear that this is not your total solution, but it should get you into the right direction. Also, I haven't tested this code myself, so it might need some tweaks here and there to get it to work properly for you.

Comment: Is this how should i do ?

Comment: $product->setSku($item->sku)
            //->setEan($item->ean)
            ->setProductID($item->product_id)
            ->setName($item->name)
            ->setDescription($item->description)
            ->setKeyword($item->keyword)
            ->setPrice($item->Price)
            ->setQtr($item->Quantity)
            ->setS_descriotion($item->S_description)
            ->setStatus($item->Status)
            ->setVisibility($item->Visibility)
            ->SetWeight($item->Weight)
            // Continue setting all other attribute values
            ->save()

Comment: @rameez.hashmi did you test this code?

Comment: yes i'm getting error. Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @rameez.hashmi have you done some debugging yet? This error means that the data I use for the `foreach` loop is incorrect. You need to find out what you should use.